# How to handle form submission vuejs

Tags: javascript, database, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a form that is supposed to get onSubmit into a database (or get it someplace so we can use the data). I tried connecting my VueJS app with Firebase, to get it inserted on the Database, however I can't accomplish it.

My form

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="billing-first-name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="billing-first-name" v-model="checkoutData.personal.first_name" required>
 </div>
```

My `<script>`

```
export default {
name: 'product',
data () {
return {
  errors: '',
  checkoutData: {
    personal: {
      first_name: '',
}
methods: {
send () {
 }
}
```

How to accomplish sending retrieved data to **firebase or any database handler**.

Comment: That is a very vague question and you have not provided any code for what you have tried. You need to make an ajax request to something. There are numerous libraries for ajax requests: axios, vue-resource, jquery, etc. The details of which we cannot provide. Do you have any code that attempts to make a request?

Comment: @kmc059000 Newbie speaking. What I'd like to do is: Submit form with Data > Send it to Database.

Answer (score 1):

The normal method is to use a third party library to post stuff.  Axios comes with the usual high recommendations for being easy to use and really light weight.

Check out https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/